# How to display icons within multi-day Event bar at specific days?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am looking for the best way to display icons at specific days within multi-day events on FullCalendar month views. The idea here is to display milestone dates within a longer period of time.

I mocked up this screenshot using relative positioning within the Event div but suspect that this could become very ugly in a hurry.

Is there a boilerplate method to do this within the context of the `eventRender` callback? Is it possible to determine the position of one day beneath/within an Event?

```
<div class="fc-event-inner fc-event-skin">
    <span class="fc-event-title">SB-019902</span>
    <img title="Stone 1" style="position: relative; left: 100px;" src="w.png" />
    <img title="Stone 2" style="position: relative; left: 200px;" src="w.png" />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop on this question my implementation went a little something like this:

Added code to FullCalendar.js between lines 4662 & 4663 to inject a table tag with one cell per day and uses the serialized date to add a CSS class attribute to indicate the date of that cell:

```
html +=
    "<div class='dayTableWrapper  " + ((seg.isStart) ? "isStart" : "isEnd") + "'><table class='dayTable'><tr>";

    for (var colNum = leftCol; colNum <= rightCol; colNum++) {
        var classDateString = formatDate(t.cellDate({ row: seg.row, col: colNum }), 'u').substring(0, 10);
        html +=
        "<td class='dayContainer dayContainer-" + colNum + " date-" + classDateString + "'></td>";
    }
html +=
    "</tr></table></div>";
html +=
    "</div>";
```

It produces markup like this:

```
<div class="fc-event-inner fc-event-skin">
    <span class="fc-event-title _fc1">Event Title</span>
    <div class="dayTableWrapper  isEnd">
        <table class="dayTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dayContainer dayContainer-0 date-2013-04-07"></td>
                    <td class="dayContainer dayContainer-1 date-2013-04-08"></td>
                    <td class="dayContainer dayContainer-2 date-2013-04-09"></td>
                    <td class="dayContainer dayContainer-3 date-2013-04-10"></td>
                    <td class="dayContainer dayContainer-4 date-2013-04-11"></td>
                    <td class="dayContainer dayContainer-5 date-2013-04-12"></td>
                    <td class="dayContainer dayContainer-6 date-2013-04-13"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was then able to target the individual cells of the week by index or by date value in order to add the icon images that represented a milestone element.